# "/var/tmp/Ex08470" Permission denied

Tags: unix

I am running Unix(Solaris 10 Server) in my company and we have Oracle database installed on it. When I am trying to login into oracle using oracle(this user made specially to access oracle) user with command

> "sqlplus system/system as sysdba"

the prompt says it can't find the sqlplus command. So I went into the home directory of oracle user and tried to open-up .profile file it gives me following error:

> ""/var/tmp/Ex08470" Permission denied"

and the string after /var/tmp/ always keep changing with every retry.

I googled and found out following answer:

1. Login as root.

   > chmod 755 /var
   >
   > chmod 1777 /var/tmp
   >
   > NOTE: This is in case the permissions has been screwed up, even though "ll -d" commd shows everything is O.K.
2. Login as the user.

> umask (check umask settings)
>
> umask 077
>
> vi .profile
>   ... edit & save ..

Can anyone explain it to me as what is happening here?

Comment: Voting to move question to Serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

The user's vi editor is attempting to create a temporary file in the /var/tmp directory when it edits the file. The user didn't have permission to create a new file in /var/tmp, which you gave the user when you issued the chmod commands (see other SF questions or wikipedia for far better explanations than I could give of [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod), [file permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions), and [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)).